# C++ makefile error "implicit entry/start for main executable"

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, compiler-errors

I have this structure for my project:

```
root
|____Makefile
|
|___src
|     |____*.cpp  
|
|___includes
|      |___*.h
|
|___obj
|___tmp
|___bin
```

The problem is that when i try to make i got this error:

```
g++ -std=c++11 obj/book.o -o bin/main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My main.cpp is inside src than i have a file .h where i declare a struct and some function and a .cpp where i define everything. In the main and in the cpp i do

```cpp
#include "../includes/myfile.h"
```

How i can compile and fix this problem?
Here is my makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -I..
LDFLAGS = -std=c++11
EXECUTABLE= bin/main
SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
HEADERS = $(wildcard includes/*.h)
OBJECTS = $(patsubst src/%.cpp, obj/%.o, $(SOURCES))

BASE = $(USER)

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean: 
    rm $(OBJECTS)

rmproper:
    rm $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)

pdf:
    a2ps Readme.txt makefile $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES) -o /tmp/out.ps
    ps2pdf /tmp/out.ps $(BASE).pdf

zip:
    zip $(BASE).zip Readme.txt makefile $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES)
```

Comment: It seems you're linking a single object file into a single executable file, and that object file (and the source file the generated it) doesn't have a `main` function. Are youre `Makefile` supposed to build and link *multiple* source (and object) files? Is the output you show the *full* build log? If you remove the object files and build again, can you copy-paste the *full* output into your question?

Comment: The problem is here:
`$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@`.

`$<` is the first prerequisite, i.e. the first object file. What you want is `$^` to list all object files.

Comment: In `$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)` rule, I believe you want to replace `$<` with `$^`. The former is "the first file from the list", the latter is "all files from the list".

Comment: @JohanBoulé Should be easier to write an actual answer now. :)

Comment: In a nutshell: you are not linking the object file defining the function. See the other comments.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, the user πάντα ῥεῖ was far too quick at marking it as a duplicate. The problem was actually in the makefile, not in the source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

`$<` is the first prerequisite, i.e. the first object file in your `$(OBJECTS)` list (which happens to be `book.o` according to your error message). What you want to pass is the whole list of object files, which can be accomplished by using either `$^`, or even `$(OBJECTS)` in place of `$<`.